# Pandas dataframe isolate row below a keyword

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas

I have a 1 column dataframe

```
df = pd.read_csv(txt_file, header=None)
```

I am trying to search for a string in the column and then return the row after

```
key_word_df = df[df[0].str.contains("KeyWord")]
```

I dont know how you can then every each time the keyword is found, isolate the row below it and assign to a new df.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the shift function. Here's an example

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'word': ['hello', 'ice', 'kitten', 'hello', 'foo', 'bar', 'hello'],
                  'val': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]})

    val word
0   1   hello
1   2   ice
2   3   kitten
3   4   hello
4   5   foo
5   6   bar
6   7   hello

keyword = 'hello'
df[(df['word']==keyword).shift(1).fillna(False)]

    val word
1   2   ice
4   5   foo
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `.shift` method on an indexer. I've split this into multiple lines to demonstrate what's happening, but you could do the operation in a one-liner for brevity in practice.

```
import pandas as pd
# 1. Dummy DataFrame with strings
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame(["one", "two", "one", "two", "three"], columns=["text",])

# 2. Create the indexer, use `shift` to move the values down one and `fillna` to remove NaN values
In [2]: idx = df["text"].str.contains("one").shift(1).fillna(False)
In [3]: idx
Out [3]:
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
Name: text, dtype: bool

# 3. Use the indexer to show the next row from the matched values:
In: [4] df[idx]
Out: [4]
text
1  two
3  two
```

Comment: you can do shift(),. default is 1 :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way.

Get the index of the rows that match your condition. Then use `.loc` to get the matching index + 1.

Consider the following example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({0: ['KeyWord', 'foo', 'bar', 'KeyWord', 'blah']})
print(df)
#         0
#0  KeyWord
#1      foo
#2      bar
#3  KeyWord
#4     blah
```

Apply the mask, and get the rows of the index + 1:

```
key_word_df = df.loc[df[df[0].str.contains("KeyWord")].index + 1, :]
print(key_word_df)
#      0
#1   foo
#4  blah
```